# Import raster using raster2pgsql with out-of-db option not working

Tags: postgis, raster, import

I am using raster2pgsql to import DTED data into postgis database.
I would like the data to be out-of-db, I am using the command as follows.

```
raster2pgsql -R /home/gis/elevation/DTED/area.dt2 public.dted
```

But the sql generated from this shows that the data is inserted into the table and there is no reference to the filename.
What am I missing here?

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the data that is inserted into the table is rasterdata? Also the metadata will be binary so it is hard to tell, except for the size of it.  Does removing the raster from the filesystem still gives you access to it from within postgres? If not, it must have been outdb.

Comment: On a side note: you have to enable outdb rasters before they work: postgis_enable_outdb_rasters

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Raster metadata wasn't stored in the `raster_columns` view.

[image: Table schema without -C parameter]

Adding `-C` parameter (apply raster constraints) solved it. Nevertheless it turned out that even without `-C` parameter querying the raster works fine.

```
raster2pgsql  -s 4326 -I -d -R -C D:\GIS\random_raster.tif rasters_outdb_local_drive.random_raster | psql.exe
```

[image: Table schema with -C parameter]